# Can Google Earth App for the iPad specify a KML using a URL without dealing with Google MyMaps?

Tags: kml, google-earth, ipad

Can Google Earth App for the iPad specify a KML using a URL without having to go through  with one's Google My Maps Account?

Answer (score 2):

Yes with the deprecation of the Maps DATA API
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/11/maps-data-api-deprecation-announcement.html

**you can now use v3 Google Maps API with Fusion Tables**

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/map-your-data-with-maps-api-and-fusion.html

(this becomes the default and will be official on 1st Feb 2011)

Comment: Actually the Fusion Tables information is very interesting Thanks. But that wasnt my question. I am using Google Earth on iPad (not Google Maps) and wanted to view simple KMLs (not tabular geodata) overlayed onto 3-D Google Earth. I wanted to know if I could do this by storing my KMLs outside of Google My Maps?

Comment: You can store KML files anywhere that is publicly accessible via the web with a valid url, Google encourage you to do this (and they index KML geographically).

Comment: thanks...On an iPad, I think that when using Google Earth app it is not possible to specify any URL as it is with the normal PC Google Earth.